# How can I load my dataset including the labels in jupyter notebook using anaconda?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

can someone help me with load both datasets, the main dataset with the labeled dataset to be load on my Jupiter notebook.

Comment: "Can somebody help me" questions are not welcome here, instead of asking for human help, you need to describe your issue in detail, so people can actually help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a dataset, depending on what file type the dataset is in, you can use functions such as:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("#FileNameHere")
```

Then concatenate the two dataframes into one with all the attributes and labels.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: The dataset is for dos attack and the label has the number between 0 or 1 and would this function still work?

Comment: @SarahCrafton It should work. You can try testing the code out. Please accept & upvote my answer if it helps so others can refer to it as well :)